# "sang differently" in Japanese

Tags: adverbs

Japanese is the only language that I know in which "different" is not an adjective but a verb (違う). I know some young Japanese are using 違く as the adverb, as if 違い were an adjective, but I am not sure if that is grammatically accepted one or not, and I would like to avoid it.

So, I wanted to say "sang differently" in Japanese, and what I could think of was "違って歌った", but is it correct? I know there is an expression like "違って見えた" (looked differently), but in that case, it could be interpreted as "違っているように見えた", and I cannot explain exactly but that seems different from the verb sang.

In short, is "違って歌った" correct? If not, what is the correct way to modify the verb 歌う with a word for "differently"? Or do I have to work around it like "違う方法で歌った"?

Comment: 違って歌った would mean "was different and sang" or "sang so that it was different".

Answer (score 5):

I would say [違]{ちが}う[歌]{うた}い[方]{かた}をした.

違うふうに歌った would also make sense.

違って歌った doesn't make much sense.